# How do you run an if statement after a condition has been met?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am currently trying to have an if statement run after soulamount is 10. However, the if statement only works when soulamount is 0. This is due to soulamount being set at 0 to begin with. However, when the user clicks a button, the soulamount goes up. I'm assuming the if statement is not working as intended due to it running as soon as the page loads. So, how do I go about running the if statement when soulamount reaches 10?

```
let soulAmount = 0;
let soulAddition = 1;
let grabSps = document.querySelector(".sps").innerHTML;
let sps = parseInt(grabSps);
let upgradecost1 = 10;

function getSoul() {
    soulAmount += soulAddition;
    document.querySelector(".souls_amount").innerHTML = soulAmount;
    return soulAmount;
}

function upgrade1() {
    if (soulAmount >= upgradecost1) {
        sps += 1;
        soulAmount -= upgradecost1;
        document.querySelector(".souls_amount").innerHTML = soulAmount;
        document.querySelector(".sps").innerHTML = sps;
        return soulAmount;
    } else {
        alert("You do not have enough souls!")
    }
}

window.setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector(".souls_amount").innerHTML = soulAmount += sps;
}, 1000);


if(soulAmount == 10) {
    console.log(soulAmount)
}

function achievement1() {
    alert("Achievement Unlocked. You've collected 100 Souls!")
    document.getElementById("collect100").style.display = "block"
}
```

I have tried searching for results but got nowhere. Someplace stated to not use an assignment operator and use "==" or "===" instead, but that didn't help. In the end, I realised the problem, I just dont know how to overcome it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function called validateSoul that I added anywhere your soul variable is being modified. This way anytime the value of soul is changed, you can verify its value and do what is needed.

```
let soulAmount = 0;
let soulAddition = 1;
let grabSps = document.querySelector(".sps").innerHTML;
let sps = parseInt(grabSps);
let upgradecost1 = 10;

function validateSoul(){
    if(soulAmount === 10){
      console.log("!!!")
    }
}

function getSoul() {
    soulAmount += soulAddition;
    validateSoul();
    document.querySelector(".souls_amount").innerHTML = soulAmount;
    return soulAmount;
}

function upgrade1() {
    if (soulAmount >= upgradecost1) {
        sps += 1;
        soulAmount -= upgradecost1;
        validateSoul();
        document.querySelector(".souls_amount").innerHTML = soulAmount;
        document.querySelector(".sps").innerHTML = sps;
        return soulAmount;
    } else {
        alert("You do not have enough souls!")
    }
}

window.setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector(".souls_amount").innerHTML = soulAmount += sps;
    validateSoul();
}, 1000);

function achievement1() {
    alert("Achievement Unlocked. You've collected 100 Souls!")
    document.getElementById("collect100").style.display = "block"
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks so much! I spent hours trying to figure it out before looking for help. I should've known I could've just done that... must be tired ahaha. Thank you!